# Proper Nginx regex for redirection of URLs with double hyphen

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

This is my first post ever. Hopefully, I'll be able to explain my problem thouroughly.

I have an Nginx config that redirects my.domain.com/avocado to my.domain.com/avocado/ (with a slash in the end). This also redirect subpaths (end with a slash) after the /avocado path like:

my.domain.com/avocado/banana --> my.domain.com/avocado/banana/
my.domain.com/avocado/banana/apple --> my.domain.com/avocado/banana/apple/

Now, we noticed that URLs with "/--" as the last subpath (example: my.domain.com/avocado/banana/apple/--) is not redirecting correctly. It should redirect to my.domain.com/avocado/banana/apple/ (append a slash to the last subpath)

I think this is regex stuff too but I have no idea how to correctly do it. Would you guys suggest any regex? Thank you!

```
server {
  server_name my.domain.com;
  location /avocado {
    resolver 10.1.0.2 valid=60s;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
    }
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ https://$server_name$1/ permanent;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://$upstreamserver$request_uri;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your first question and my first answer then.

I see two ways to do this.

1. `^([^.]*)(?:(?<!/|--)|/--)$`

   - `^([^.]*)` from the start of the line, capture everything that is not a dot as many times as possible, giving back as needed.
   - `(?:(?<!/|--)|/--)$` captures the end of the line when there isn't a `/` or `/--` before it, or the `/--` at the end of the line if it exists, then replaces them with `/`.
   - [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TUxKcX/1)
2. `^([^.]*?)(?:/--)?(?<!/)$`

   - `^([^.]*?)` from the start of the line, capture everything that is not a dot as few times as possible, expanding as needed.
   - `(?:/--)?` match `/--` if it exsists but don't capture it.
   - `(?<!/)$` match if the end of the line isn't preceeded by `/`.
   - [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cOVMkV/1)

Comment: Thanks for this! It solved my problem. Upvoted for the first time as well. :)